# c# web api - Running web application with HTTPS - Added certificate and enabled SSL but am getting connection refused

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, ssl-certificate

I have a web application that I have been developing with a c# web api self hosted with OWIN as the backend that interacts with an angular front end. It has worked great but now I am trying to have it run on https rather than http am and having trouble.

> I have enabled SSL:

[image]

> I have changed the url to https:

[image]

> I have added the localhost certificate to my Personal Certificates:

[image]

> which is also in my trusted certificates:

[image]

Yet when I run my application in VS2013 now it immediately returns with the error:

> This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Any idea?

Comment: Did you remember to change the url in your angular client? Also, I don't think you need the change the Project Url in your second screenshot. Do you get a response when you access the url directly in a browser? Try using a different port for SSL than for non-SSL.

Comment: I have reverted the second screenshot back to http. I used a different port for SSL than non-SSL and ran the application. It ran with non SSL and when I changed the port in the url I got the response: "This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Answer (score 0):

If you are still experiencing this issue try to repair IIS Express. This worked in my case.